# Razor массив в ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть необходимость засунуть в массив несколько строк (в контроллере) и затем эти строки через цикл вывести.
То есть, в контроллере сделать что-то типа:

```
    ....  
ViewBag.MyArray[cnt] = "sd";  - //как правильно реализовать эту строку? Ибо тут ругается.
....
```

А во Views вывести:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.MyArray.Length; i++)
{
    ViewBag.MyArray[i];
}
```

На всякий случай, какая ошибка выводится в браузере:

> **Description:** An unhandled exception
> occurred during the execution of the
> current web request. Please review the
> stack trace for more information about
> the error and where it originated in
> the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**
> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
> Cannot perform runtime binding on a
> null reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед обращением к массиву нужно его создать.
Например, так:

```
ViewBag.MyArray = new string[10];
ViewBag.MyArray[0] = "First string";
ViewBag.MyArray[1] = "Second string";
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что надо. :)